# How to join an ID from table to a coloumn in another table sql

Tags: php, sql, join, html-table, union

I have two database tables: `Criteria` and `Students`,

Criteria Table 
consists of `Criteria ID, description, marks available`.

Students Table
consists of `Student ID, Name, Criteria1 Mark Achieved, Criteria2 Mark Achieved, Criteria3 Mark Achieved`.

This is my current sql statement:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM criteria, students where studentID=$id");
```

I am trying to create a table where I can display the marks available(from criteria table) with the marks achieved(from students table). Do I need to contain some sort of join e.g. criteria id 1 (criteria table) be linked with criteria1 mark achieved (students table) baring in mind there are many students?

Comment: Step 1, which sql server are you using, it makes a different to be able to answer your question. Step 2), post a table structure or sample data along with intended output. How are the two tables joined, I can't tell from your question.

Comment: You might need three tables.Students table, criteria_join table that joins students to criterias and a criteria table.

Comment: Something like this: `SELECT *
FROM students
INNER JOIN criteria_join
 ON students.id = criteria_join.student_id
INNER JOIN criteria
 ON criteria_join.criteria_id = criteria.id
WHERE students.id = 123`

Answer (score 0):

Criteria Table: consists of Criteria ID, description, marks_available.

Students Table:consists of Student ID,Criteria ID, Name, Criteria1_Mark_Achieved, Criteria2_Mark_Achieved, Criteria3_Mark_Achieved.

Now the sql statement is:

$query = ("SELECT * FROM c.*, s.* from Criteria c
             INNER JOIN Student s ON c.Criteria_Id=s.Criteria_id");